# Python: Change class member in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently trying to change member variables of a class via a separate thread. I want to access the changed variables from the main process, but it seems that a copy is always created that is no longer visible to the main thread. Do you have any ideas here?
Many thanks in advance for your help.
Example code:

```
class foo():
 def __init__(self):
     self.data = 0

 def test_f(self):
     for it in range(0,3):
         self.data = self.data + 1
         time.sleep(1.0)
     print('thread terminated')
     print(self.data)

#This function is outside the class; Unfortunately, indentations do not work properly here right now

def run(m_foo):
 for it in range(0,10):
     m_foo.test_f(q)
     time.sleep(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 m_foo = foo()
 p = Process(target=run, args=(m_foo))
 p.start()     
stop_char = ""
while stop_char.lower() != "q":
    stop_char = input("Enter 'q' to quit\n")        
    print("Process data:")
    print(foo.data)
if p.is_alive():
   p.terminate()
```

> Output:
> Process data:
> 0
> ....
> thread terminated
> 21
> thread terminated
> 24
> thread terminated
> 27
> thread terminated
> 30
> ...
> Process data:
> 0

Comment: A ``Process`` is not a thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `multiprocessing.Process` does not create a thread. It creates a completely new processing with its own memory space.

Use `threading.Thread` instead:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread